# Is it meaningful to find linear convolution of just two random sequences?

Tags: convolution

Could it bring any meaning? Is this kind of convolution be useful is solving anything?

Comment: This question does not seem very meaningful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, if the two sequences are random then convolving them is not useful.